# How can I send hundreds of photos via email to someone not technically savvy?

Tags: photo-sharing

I have a lot of photos I'd like to send to family. Normally I'd send it in a .zip file, but they aren't too technically inclined.

Are there any web applications where I can upload a lot of pictures that they can easily browse?

Bonus if the user can download the photos/album with easy-to-follow instructions on how to do so.

Comment: **[Windows Live Skydrive](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive)** - 25GB free storage...restricted access...

Comment: [Dropbox](https://dropbox.com)?

Answer (score 4):

www.dropbox.com! It can't be easier, no need to mess around with proprietary photo albums. It can be installed with a few clicks (same for registration), is cross-plattform (Windows, Mac, Linux) and after all it's just a folder on your file system that is kept in sync with an online folder. Of course that folder can be shared with others...

Comment: +1 for dropbox. If you can talk your family member through installing DropBox (it's dead easy), then you can send them a shared folder with your pictures, and they can view it on their computer.

Comment: I like Dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

Picasa, Flickr, the new one [min.us](http://min.us), all of them do that.

The best one for private sharing by email, though, is Flickr.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an album on Facebook.

They don't have to sign up to be able to view it. At the bottom of every album it states:

> Share this album with anyone by sending them this public link:
>   http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=207460&id=679700476&l=a4f35a762a

where the "Share this..." is a mail to link.

They won't be able to download the photos easily though.

You can make the album private by selecting the "Edit album info" link and then making it visible only to specific people on Facebook.

Other photo sharing sites (Picassa, Photo Bucket, Imagur etc.) are also available.

Comment: I would rather not upload to Facebook, as I just want family to see it and not anyone else I have added. Even though a web application would be public, it'd at least be anonymous and nobody would care.

Comment: @Corey - you can restrict access to the album - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Picasa. Get the client, add your pics and upload to one or more Picasa web albums. You can make the album(s) private to hide them from everyone apart from specific people you choose to share them with.

You could probably use Flickr in a similar way but I've only used Google's Picasa so I'm recommending that.

Answer (score 0):

I use Pic Resizer for Android to resize hundreds of photos and send them quickly to friends.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.pham.picresizerlite